# SQLite unsure about ALL syntax

Tags: sqlite, syntax

I'm trying to find out which customer spent the most on orders, in addition to how much they have spent in total.

This is my current code. However, im getting a syntax error near `ALL`

```
SELECT c.id, sum(i.Quantity * p.UnitPrice) AS TotalSpend
FROM Customers c, Orders o, OrderItems i, Products p
WHERE c.id = o.CustomerID
AND o.id = i.OrderID
AND i.ProductID = p.id
AND sum(i.Quantity * p.UnitPrice) > ALL(
    SELECT sum(i.Quantity * p.UnitPrice)
    FROM OrderItems i, Products p
    WHERE i.ProductID = p.id)
```

Not too sure where i have committed the syntax error

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the keyword ALL is not supported by SQLite.

Comment: It returns the same syntax error of Result: near "ALL": syntax error